# Reducing the input width of input in bulma

Tags: css, responsive-design, bulma

I'm having hard time reducing the input width and making it responsive. Right now, my form looks like this:

[image: desktop view]
[image: mobile view]

As you can see the inputs are having full width. I tried giving it a style of `width:33%` and `textAlign: "center"` to the parent but it didn't work. I just want the form to be centered and responsive.

---

Here's the code.

```
<div className="field">
  <p className="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
    <input
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      name="username"
      value={this.state.username}
      className="input is-rounded"
      type="text"
      placeholder="Username"
    />
    <span className="icon is-small is-left">
      <i className="fas fa-user"></i>
    </span>
    <span className="icon is-small is-right">
      <i className="fas fa-check"></i>
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to wrap your input fields in column that is width controlled as below;

```
<div class="column is-3">

      <!-- your code here -->

</div>
```